# Does timeout work with HTTPS proxy requests in Mechanize?

Tags: python, https, proxy, mechanize, mechanize-python

I know urllib2 has issues with timeout, so maybe Mechanize has similar issues.

I'm using the following code to test if a HTTPS proxy is good. However, this is running for ever with some proxies. For example, a thread for testing 900 proxies has been running at an incrementing amount of CPU for like 9 hours. When timeout was working (before HTTPS, but rather just HTTP), it would take <15 minutes to run regularly.

```
Br = mechanize.Browser()
Br.set_proxies({"https": self.proxy,})
try:
    response = Br.open("https://www.tumblr.com/", timeout=5)
    return True
except:
    return False
```

Any ideas? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mechanize uses [fork of `urllib2`](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py) under the hood. This might be relevant.